# How to change the days of week into SUN, TUE, etc

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, date-fns

I used a CalendarPicker of the new version of material-ui (*v5*) and I can't seem to find a way to manipulate the default days of week initials. From the image below I want it to change from

> S, M, T, W, T, F, S

into

> SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIiTx.png)

Here's my sample code:

```
import React from "react"
import isWeekend from "date-fns/isWeekend"
import MuiCalendarPicker from "@mui/lab/CalendarPicker"
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns"
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider"
import { ComponentWrapper } from "./CalendarPicker.style"

interface Props {}

const CalendarPicker: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(new Date())

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <ComponentWrapper>
        <MuiCalendarPicker<Date>
          openTo="day"
          date={value}
          shouldDisableDate={isWeekend}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue)
          }}
        />
      </ComponentWrapper>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}

export default CalendarPicker
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a function with a switch inside of it that takes in the date, gets the day number in the week and spits out whatever string you want for the day
For eg:

```
const formatDay = (date) => {
  switch(date.getDay()){
    case 0: 
      return "SUN"
    case 1:
     return "MON"
    case 2:
     return "TUES"
    .......
}
}
```

Then, you examine the mui lib inside your `node_modules` folder and wrap what gets returned by them with this function and you're good to go

Comment: Let me look at this. Thank you for the response!